# Length of a curve given by a function and distance covered by a projectile

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, projectile-motion

Using differentiation, the slope of a curve can be found and using integration, the area under the curve is found.

**How can calculus be used to determine the length of the curve represented by a given function?**

If equation of trajectory of the proectile is given by y=f(x) which represents a parabola in a uniform gravitational field, I formulated the integral to find distance covered by the projectile as:
 [image: R is the range of the proectile]
(R being the range)

*I applied it in this question:*
[image]

*to find the total distance in order to find average speed.*

*However I did not get the right answer.*

***What changes need to be made in the integral?
  What will be the integral used to find total distance in this question?***

Comment: f '(x) is the 1st derivative of the function

Comment: I'm not sure to understand completely your question, the length of the graph determined by the a function $y=f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$. What is the definition of average speed and avarage velocity?

Comment: could you just used the kinematic equation from physics?

Comment: Average speed in total distance upon total time and total distance is the path length or the length of parabola given by the equation of trajectory so I wanted to find total distance

Comment: I knew arc length is approximately equal to chord length for small value of h, I integrated the differnce of 1st derivative as in the question Average velocity is total displacement upon total time and total displacement is just magnitud of difference of position vectors

Comment: You want to find the total difference, and Andrea S. has provided you with the correct integral formula to do so. I can't even follow your thought process that led to the integral in your post, but for continuous $f$, it easily reduces to $\lim_{h \to 0}(f(R + h)-f(h) - f(R)+f(0)) = 0$, so it is not a measure of anything.